# Building dynamic queries with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

So, I have form for my project where I can create users into database. There
are three types of user types, admins, moderators and end users.

**My query for creating the users table is following:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (

    id SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    user_type ENUM('admin','moderator','enduser'),
    phone_number VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,

    school_id SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_school_id
    FOREIGN KEY (school_id)
    REFERENCES schools(id)
    ON UPADTE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,

    subject_id SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_subject_id
    FOREIGN KEY (subject_id)
    REFERENCES subjects(id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT

) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

So the school_id and subject_id are working as a foreign keys.

In my form, I have select menu where I can choose to create a certain type of user. If I choose to create admin, form will not display the hidden select menus for school and subject. If I choose to create moderator, form will display the hidden select menus. This is done with JavaScript.

Everything works well when I create an admin. It will store all the values in the database and sets school_id and subject_id values to NULL. Problem occurs when I decide to create a moderator. It still sets the school_id and subject_id values to even though I've set those values in my select menus.

I know I need to build a dynamic query. Just don't know how to implement it in the right way in CodeIgniter. If I was just coding with spaghetti PHP, it would be a peace of cake, but since I desperately want to learn using MVC frameworks, that is not an option.

Here's my model:

```
public function add_user($data) {

    $data = array(
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => $data['password'],
            'user_type' => $data['user_type'],
            'phone_number' => $data['phone_number']
        );

    $this->db->insert('users', $data);
}
```

**Should I include those school_id and subject_id values in the array or not?**

Here's my controller (part of it actually):

```
    $this->load->model('user');

    $name = ucfirst($this->input->post('f_name')). " " .ucfirst($this->input->post('l_name'));

    $data = array (
            'name'          => $name,
            'email'         => $this->input->post('email'),
            'username'      => $username,
            'password'      => $this->phpass->hash($password),
            'user_type'     => $this->input->post('user_type'),
            'phone_number'  => $this->input->post('phone_number'),

        );

// Here's where I'm trying to build the dynamic part 

    if($this->input->post('school_id') && $this->input->post('subject_id'))
    {

        $data['school_id'] = $this->input->post('school_id');
        $data['subject_id'] = $this->input->post('subject_id');
    }

    if($this->user->add_user($data))
    {
    // Inserted successfully
}
```

Obviously this is not the correct way to do this since it's not working. What should I do to make it work using best possible practices?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, there is no **one** answer but a few depending on how you code. Just keep in mind to apply your logic all over your project and not change it suddenly for this or that model/controller.

As for me, I would do it like this :

**NEVER** trust user's input.

-Check for all your $data so that password/username (and whatever) are not empty ! You need to do this in javascript AND PHP !

-Seeing you won't have a lot of schools & subjects, you can check their validity (but you are using InnoDB so that's not necessary)

```
public function add_user($data)
{
    $minimalUser = array('username','password');
    if (count(array_diff($minimalUser, array_keys($data))) != 0) {
        return false;  //If a $data is missing, do not create the user !
    }

    $data = array(
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => $data['password'],
            'user_type' => $data['user_type'],
            'phone_number' => $data['phone_number'],
            'subject_id' => isset($data['subject_id']) ? $data['subject_id'] : null,
            'school_id' => isset($data['school_id']) ? $data['school_id'] : null
        );
    $this->db->insert('users', $data);
}
```

This code works for, let's say, all your cases ! Moderator, Admin & end user.

An other point : Do a check on the email provided. Something with : `filter_var("some@address.com", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`

Comment: Check my answer.. And I use CodeIgniters form_validation library, just didn't include it in here.

Comment: Answer ? So if you answered your question, there is no more problem right ? Although I don't see it as an answer.

Comment: No, of course the problem is not solved. I just decided to post it underneath instead of editing my previous post. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Well actually that didn't work. Now I'm getting a database error about foreign keys:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydatabase`.`users`, CONSTRAINT `fk_school_id` FOREIGN KEY (`school_id`) REFERENCES `schools` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

    INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `name`, `email`, `password`, `user_type`, `phone_number`, `subject_id`, `school_id`) VALUES ('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', '$2a$08$VT4QYX9kiy8i7ivLmbVVre7AQfiKxAQ.0E9jGF0PbS.PNVTTmpLK2', 'moderator', 'xxx', 0, 0)
```

Could it be because I use another controller and model to get those subjects and schools from the database?

**Controller to get all the subjects and schools:**

```
<?php

class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('subject');
    }


    public function index() {

        $data['subjects'] = $this->subject->get_all_subjects();
        $data['schools'] = $this->subject->get_all_schools();

        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }


}

?>
```

**Model to get all the schools and subjects:**

```
<?php

class Subject extends CI_Model
{

    public function get_all_subjects()
    {

        $this->db->select('*')->from('subjects')->order_by('name', 'asc');

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result_array();
    }

    public function get_all_schools()
    {

        $this->db->select('*')->from('schools')->order_by('name', 'asc');

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result_array();
    }


}


?>
```

**And my view (dashboard.php):**

```
<?php echo form_open('users/add_user', $attributes); ?>

    <span class="close_form_button_add_user_form">X</span>

    <?php echo validation_errors('<div class="login_error">', '</div>'); ?>

    <div class="form_row">
    <input type="text" name="f_name" placeholder="Etunimi" class="half-width" />
    <input type="text" name="l_name" placeholder="Sukunimi" class="half-width" style="float: right; margin-right: 24px;"/>
    </div>


    <div class="form_row">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Uuden käyttäjän sähköpostiosoite" class="user full-width" />
    </div>


    <div class="form_row">
    <input type="email" name="email_confirm" placeholder="Sähköpostiosoite uudelleen" class="user full-width" />
    </div>

    <div class="form_row">
    <input type="text" name="phone_number" placeholder="Puhelinnumero (0401234567)" class="full-width" />
    </div>


    <div class="form_row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <select name="user_type" class="add_user_select" id="select_user_type">
        <option value="">Käyttäjätyyppi</option>
        <option value="admin">Hallinto</option>
        <option value="moderator">Hallinto 2</option>
        <option value="enduser">Pääkäyttäjä</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="add_user" value="Luo käyttäjä" class="login_submit" id="submit_user" style="margin: 5px 24px 0px 0px;"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form_row" id="add_user_optional_information">
    <select name="school" class="add_user_select half-width">
        <option value="">Koulutalo</option>
        <?php  foreach($schools as $school) :?>
        <option value="<?=$school['id']?>"><?=$school['name']?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>

    <select name="subject" class="add_user_select half-width">
        <option value="">Laji</option>
        <?php  foreach($subjects as $subject) :?>
        <option value="<?=$subject['id']?>"><?=$subject['name']?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    </div>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: This shouldn't be an answer but an edit to your post. Whatever, the problem is that you want to insert 0,0 to school_id, subject_id. And foreign_key is telling you that such school & subject do not exist. In my code, try this instead `'subject_id' => empty($data['subject_id']) ? null : $data['subject_id']` (and the same with school_id)